# switch with a negative value for size_t

Tags: c

If I have the following snippet:

```
size_t num = -1;

switch(num) {
    case -1:
        printf("Minus one!\n");
        break;
    default:
        printf("Not minus one!\n");
}
```

Why is it that the program prints `Minus One!`? Is `num` casted to a `size_t` in the `switch` statement? Is this behavior defined?

Comment: What do you mean `Is num casted to a size_t?`, num is of type size_t.

Comment: No, you *explicitly declare* `num` as `type_t` and then assign -1 to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the C standard on switch:

> 6.8.4.2 The switch statement
>   ...
>   Semantics
>   ...
>   5 The integer promotions are performed on the controlling expression. The constant
>   expression in each case label is converted to the promoted type of the controlling
>   expression. If a converted value matches that of the promoted controlling expression,
>   control jumps to the statement following the matched case label.

`size_t` is also an unsigned type per the standard (6.5.3.4 The sizeof operator, Semantics, 4).

So, your `-1` is converted to `size_t` in both `size_t num = -1;` and `case -1:`. No wonder that `(size_t)-1==(size_t)-1` evaluates to true.

Comment: But is their any way we can use negative values for case??

Comment: @PrabhatKumarSingh just make sure that the expression in `switch(expression)` and the constant in `case constant:` are both of signed types (e.g. int, long, long long).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this behavior is defined.  The values are cast to `size_t` as you'd expect.  From C99 §6.8.4.2/5:

> The integer promotions are performed on the controlling expression. The constant expression in each `case` label is converted to the promoted type of the controlling expression. If a converted value matches that of the promoted controlling expression, control jumps to the statement following the matched `case` label.

The "controlling expression" is the expression appearing inside the parentheses after the `switch` keyword, i.e. `num` in this case.

So, the `-1` in the case label is converted to `size_t` (the promoted type of `num`).  Since the value of `num` is just that, the code in that case statement is executed.